# Connect GitHub Pages to custom domain at both http:// and https://

Tags: dns, url, github, forwarding, godaddy

I've got a domain on GoDaddy at `[domain].com` that I'm trying to connect to my GitHub Pages at `[domain].github.io`.

The problem is that my site only shows up at `https://[domain].com`, not `http://[domain].com`.

In the GitHub repo, I've added my custom URL as `[domain].com`, added `[domain.com]` to the CNAME file, and checked the box to Enforce HTTPS.

On GoDaddy, I've set up the CNAME to direct from `www` to `[domain].github.io`, as well as added the four A records as recommended in the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site).

How do I get my site to load using both `https://` and `http://`? I've tried forwarding `http://` to `https://` on GoDaddy to no avail.

Comment: So there is 100% no plain HTTP access to your site at all?

Comment: Correct, it goes to a page that says my domain may be for sale, @Giacomo1968

Comment: Odd because GoDaddy should at least be able to allow you to have your site respond to HTTP and HTTPS requests. So I would contact GoDaddy support and explain basically that: The site should force HTTPS but should respond to both HTTP and HTTPS. If nothing is responding to the HTTP it can’t redirect to the HTTPS.

Comment: -_- after talking with both GoDaddy and GitHub, all I had to do was reset my cache. Just wanted to note this here in case anyone else has a similar problem.

Comment: Reset the cache? On where? Your browser? I assume so. No idea what OS you are using, but the browsers are designed to cache data which make they bad debugging tools for networking issues. Instead I would recommend you use Curl from the command line to check the headers being sent from the server. So using your example, I would recommend running this command `curl -ILk http://[domain].com`. This will show you the HTTP headers and in your case it should show you at least two different status’s: First a 301 or 302 redirect to HTTPS and the final status should be 200; meaning HTTP OK… All is good.